# Fastest way to extract elements from a list that not matched condition in python

Tags: python, list, extract

I'm seeking the ***fastest way*** to extract all tuple members from a list under condition(s).

Example:
From a list of tuple (e.g. [(0,0,4),(1,0,3),(1,2,1),(4,0,0)]) I need to extract all members that have more than 3 in first tuple position, then more than 2 in second tuple position, and then more than 1 in last tuple position.
Which should extract in this example (4,0,0) (->first condition), nothing (->second condition) and (0,0,4),(1,0,3) (->last condition). This example is very small, I need to perform that on list of thousands of tuples.

From the code I produced from your answers, here are the results in sec:

my_naive1, like proposed by Emil Vikström? 13.0360000134

my_naive2 110.727999926

Tim Pietzcker 9.8329999446

Don 12.5640001297

```
import itertools, operator, time, copy
from operator import itemgetter


def combinations_with_replacement_counts(n, r):  #(A, N) in our example.N individuals/balls in A genotypes/boxes
   size = n + r - 1
   for indices in itertools.combinations(range(size), n-1):
       #print indices
       starts = [0] + [index+1 for index in indices]
       stops = indices + (size,)
       yield tuple(map(operator.sub, stops, starts))


xp = list(combinations_with_replacement_counts(3,20))  # a very small case

a1=time.time()
temp=[]
for n in xp:
    for n1 in xp:

        for i in xp:
            if i[0] <= min(n1[0],n[0]) or i[1] <= min(n1[1],n[1]) or i[2] <= min(n1[2],n[2]):
                temp.append(i)


a2=time.time()
for n in xp:
    for n1 in xp:
        xp_copy = copy.deepcopy(xp)
        for i in xp:
            if i[0] > min(n[0],n[0]) or i[1] > min(n[1],n[1]) or i[2] > min(n[2],n[2]):
                xp_copy.remove(i)

a3=time.time()
for n in xp:
    for n1 in xp:
        output = [t for t in xp if t[0]<=min(n[0],n[0]) or t[1]<=min(n[1],n[1]) or t[2]<=min(n[2],n[2])]
a4=time.time()

for n in xp:
    for n1 in xp:
        l1 = sorted(xp, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
        l1_fitered = []
        for item in l1:
            if item[0] <= min(n[0],n[0]):
                break
            l1_fitered.append(item)

        l2 = sorted(l1_fitered, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
        l2_fitered = []
        for item in l2:
            if item[1] <= min(n[1],n[1]):
                break
            l2_fitered.append(item)

        l3 = sorted(l2_fitered, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
        l3_fitered = []
        for item in l3:
            if item[2] <= min(n[2],n[2]):
                break
            l3_fitered.append(item)
a5=time.time()            



print "soluce my_naive1, like proposed by Emil Vikström?",a2-a1
print "soluce my_naive2",a3-a2
print "soluce Tim Pietzcker",a4-a3
print "soluce Don",a5-a4
```

Comment: My example is fitted and this is not one of the "i need a index but a database would be too easy" case but a "i need a fast method to realize hypergeometric probability computation in a huge markov chain", so repack your arrogant tone, try to open to the world that surround you with kindliness and pass your way if you didnot want to help. Thanks

Comment: OK, I have no idea what hypergeometric probability or even a Markov chain is (sounds like something to attach a dog to, or was that Pavlov?), but @eumiro has raised an important question: Do you want a single list as output, or three lists (one for each condition)?

Comment: soluce my_naive1, like proposed by Emil Vikström? 13.0360000134
soluce my_naive2 110.727999926
soluce Tim Pietzcker 9.83299994469
soluce Don 12.5640001297

Comment: Thanks for sharing the performance results!

Comment: Thanks, but what are all those `min(n[1],n[1])` calls? And why are you iterating over `xp` in a nested way, sometimes three times? Right now, those comparisons are rather meaningless, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> l = [(0,0,4), (1,0,3), (1,2,1), (4,0,0)]
>>> output = [t for t in l if t[0]>3 or t[1]>2 or t[2]>1]
>>> output
[(0, 0, 4), (1, 0, 3), (4, 0, 0)]
```

This is fast because `t[1]>2` is only evaluated if `t[0]>3` is `False` (same for the third condition). So in your example list, only 8 comparisons are necessary.

You might save time and memory (depending on what you're doing with the filtered data) if you use a generator expression instead:

```
>>> l = [(0,0,4), (1,0,3), (1,2,1), (4,0,0)]
>>> for item in (t for t in l if t[0]>3 or t[1]>2 or t[2]>1):
>>>     # do something with that item
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants to output three different lists.

Comment: No, I need a list of the tuple that agree the conditions, and no need to order then as presume DON (I will calculate for each kept tuple a probability from the 3 numbers they contain)

Answer (score 3):

Have three lists, one for each condition, and just loop through the input set with a for loop, sorting each tuple into the correct target list. This will perform in O(n) (linear) time, which is the fastest possible asymptotic runtime for this problem. It will also only loop over the list once.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care the order of resulting items, I suggest a lookup in sorted list, with break condition on first non-matching item:
 this would skip list tails.

```
from operator import itemgetter
l = [(..., ..., ...), (...)]
l1_source = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
l1_fitered = []
for item in l1:
    if item[0] <= 3:
        break
    l1_fitered .append(item)

l2 = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
...
```

Comment: I will try this way (I also was thinking if a sorting method could get faster) but sort need at least one loop over the list? no? If so Tim Pietzcker and Emil Vikström methods should do it faster in most cases but if my conditions non-match a lot of tuples?

Comment: It depends on how pre-sorted the list is. If it's completely random, it might eat up the performance benefit from this interesting approach. In the end, if it's really performance critical, you'll have to time it. Fortunately, there's the `timeit` module for that.

Comment: It also depends on how heavy the filtering condition is. Have a look on http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html: maybe you can find something useful